# Lenovo Laptop Notebook- cracked screen

Tags: lenovo-laptop

It won't let me post a picture... I need 10 reputation somethings... I am so upset right now...

I woke up, went to go turn on my Lenovo Notebook, which is less than a year old, and when it turned on, the screen was cracked towards the middle bottom and completely damaged, lines everywhere...

There's no way anything was making it overheat, I always open it carefully from the center with two hands, and there was nothing heavy that could've fallen on it, and it was DEFINITELY completely turned off, no programs running, laptop completely shut, no weird foreign objects stuck in it... I'm pretty much devastated. This was the first completely new computer I ever purchased for myself, and I am always careful as HELL with it. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Take it to a laptop repair shop and ask them to replace the screen.  I am going to vote your question to be close, since there really is only one solution, replace the screen and we can't help with that

Comment: How old is the laptop?  What is the model?  Is it out of warranty?  Screens can be replaced, but it won't be a cheap repair to have a shop do it (it could be a substantial fraction of a replacement laptop).  If the laptop is in the neighborhood of say 4 yrs old, it will be approaching the life expectancy of some of the other components.  In that case, you would be on a path of eventually spending the cost of a new laptop to keep the old one running.  That is rarely a good investment.  (cont'd)

Comment: If your laptop is fairly new, you will have to be the judge of whether it's a good investment.  If you don't need the portability, DrMoishe Pippik's suggestion of using it with an external monitor is a good solution.

Comment: @Ramhound, the question is a legitimate, on-topic question.  Replacing the screen is not the only solution (see DrMoishe Pippik's answer).  Even if it was the only solution, it is one we can answer here--solution: replace the screen.  That is helping with the problem.  I even recall answers here that describe how to do it.  We'd have no questions if the requirement was that somebody here show up at the OP's house and fix it.  :-)

Comment: If the question itself was a better quality question I might agree.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is possible for a user to replace a broken screen, and one can buy a [replacement (depending on model, which you do not state)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004NP8ARI) for ~US$50, if you do not have any experience repairing small electronic devices, it might be better to take it to a repair shop or computer store and get an estimate. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GLaiMj40Jo), for example, on repair of a G560 to give you an idea of what is involved in the repair.

An alternative would be to get an inexpensive LCD monitor and use the laptop as a desktop, instead -- you might like it even better that way, since the monitor can be larger and higher resolution than the laptop was.